# To remove the back arrow button from Action Bar

Tags: java, android

In my Android Project, whenever I go from First Activity to Second, I get an left arrow button followed by the some text in the action bar. That left arrow only comes when I set my First Activity as the hierarchical parent of the Second Activity.

I want to remove that back button and replace it with an icon. I have read other posts for the same question, and so I have already tried the following code in my onCreate() method.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

But after reaching to the second activity, the app gets crashed.

Please help me out.

Comment: post you AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 7):

Use `getSupportActionBar()` bar:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);
```

Comment: This should be followed up with a little more details as to why it fixes the OP's issue.