# Is it possible remove home button from actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-homebutton, appbar

On my main activity, where there is no way to go back, I'd like to remove the app "home" button in the actionbar.

I think it is confusing for the user, who still can quit the app with the OS back button.

Browsing stackoverflow, I saw a whole lot of people asking this, and not a single answer worked for me. Here is the list :

- [Removing left arrow from the actionbar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771532/removing-left-arrow-from-the-actionbar-in-android)
- [To remove the back arrow button from Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606246/to-remove-the-back-arrow-button-from-action-bar)
- [Remove default home/up button in action mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697828/remove-default-home-up-button-in-action-mode)
- [how to hide up button in actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055272/how-to-hide-up-button-in-actionbar)
- [How to remove v7 toolbar back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615806/how-to-remove-v7-toolbar-back-button)
- [Setting HomeAsUpEnabled(true) but hide back button actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132061/setting-homeasupenabledtrue-but-hide-back-button-actionbar)

The answers were usually redondant and could be summarized to following :

```
ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar(); //I target some low API
if(supportActionBar != null) {
    supportActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    supportActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    supportActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(null);
}
```

I tried every combination of those and nothing worked, whether I try with the default `ActionBar` or with an XML-declared compat-v7 `ToolBar` with `setSupportActionBar()`.

I also couldn't see any question adapted for the now recommanded [App Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html), and an answer with it would be even greater.

Here is my activity manifest :

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.WelcomeActivity"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/long_app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

So, is it even possible to remove this annoying useless arrow nowadays ?

Comment: Where is your action bar coming from? Are you using a `Toolbar` and calling `setSupportActionBar()` or are you just using the default action bar from themes? What does the manifest entry for your activity look like?

Comment: I tried both using the default `ActionBar` and setting an App Bar in my XML (with a `NoActionBar` theme in the manifest)

Comment: are you using custom action bar theme or custom app theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new style in styles.xml:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Set this style to your activity in Manifest file. To add the Toolbar, add this to your layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and then in your Java class:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

This will remove the top left arrow.

Comment: Did you try this yourself ? It don't work for me (top left arrow is still there) but I really wonder whether the fault is on my side or not. (also I think you mistook the id :-) )

Comment: OK, it was because of the XML-declared theme of the Toolbar. Works fine now, thanks !

Answer (score -1):

simply put `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)`in onCreate of the activity.